# Rails 3 - What's wrong with this migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app running. I want to create a UserNotifications migration that belongs_to user. But the migration keeps erroring.

```
class CreateUserNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :user_notifications do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.boolean :notify_news, :default => true
      t.boolean :notify_research, :default => true
      t.timestamps

    end

    # Ensure Existing users have a notification setting
    User.all.each do |u|
      UserNotification.create_by_user_id(u.id)
      user.save
    end

add_index :user_notifications, :user_id
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :user_notifications
  end
end
```

To make sure I'm asking a clear q, here is the model info:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_notification, :dependent => :destroy

class UserNotification < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user
```

**ERROR:**

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in /Users/bhellman/Sites/cline)
==  CreateUserNotifications: migrating ========================================
-- create_table(:user_notifications)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "user_notifications_id_seq" for serial column "user_notifications.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "user_notifications_pkey" for table "user_notifications"
   -> 0.2942s
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `create_by_user_id' for UserNotification(Table doesn't exist):Class
```

Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
User.all.each do |u|
  UserNotification.create(:user_id => u.id)
end
```

The error could be due to the DB schema rails is referring to isn't up to date (and therefore doesn't respond to the dynamic methods). You might also want to try

```
UserNotification.reset_column_information
```

before using `create_by_user_id` (i.e. above the block)

Comment: I don't think so: the belongs_to should be satisfied by your specifying the user_id field in the UserNotification instance

Answer (score 1):

Your `self.up` code is being run in a database transaction.  So when you're trying to run your create methods, the new table isn't officially in existence yet.  You can move it to a separate migration, but there is a much better way.

You should build a rake task to do this, and keep it out of the migration entirely.  I've written a blog post about this:

[Adding Columns and Default Data to Existing Models](http://kconrails.com/2010/01/25/adding-columns-and-default-data-to-existing-models-in-ruby-on-rails/)

The section "More Complex Default Values" goes over the reasons you shouldn't put code like this in a migration.  The main reason is that migrations "rot" over time - as your code base changes, older migrations stop working.

If you have any questions, let me know.  I hope this helps!

Comment: I would say that it should belong in the migration if the DB has to be "brought up to speed" to conform to the new schema, e.g. the application will never (under any circumstances) allow a User to be without a UserNotification (and therefore, all users should have notifications after the migration). If on the other hand, you're going to make sure more than once that all User objects have a UserNotification, then yes, I'd put it in a rake task. Is there something wrong with my line of thinking?